# webfont causing div to not adjusting for correct height

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane

I'm using webfont service and I'm having issues with jscrollpane.

I assume jscrollpane is getting the height from the font before it switches to webfont which being slightly bigger makes the div slightly longer. jscrollpane doesn't correctly update the height and thus cuts off text.

I thought `autoReinitialise:true` would correctly adjust the height.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function()
        {
        $('.info').jScrollPane({showArrows: true, autoReinitialise: true});
        });
});
```

Can I put a delay on the script firing to wait for the webfont, or how can I use autoReinitialise.

Any help would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$(window).load()`instead of `$(document).ready()`, this ensures, that the webfont is loaded when you initialize your jScrollPane.

Comment: window.load took too long to load the scroll bar and jumped the page. So I added additional padding to the bottom of the last paragraph of text to adjust for the font-size changing. Thanks for your answer.